# Mixed effects model on panel data with 2 indexing variables using lme4?

Tags: r, regression, lme4, mixed-models, panel-data

I want to create a linear mixed-effects model which indexes by both `ID` and `year`. I have never worked with longitudinal data before and I'm not sure how to approach modelling the data I have.

The data set looks like this:

```r
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
                   year = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3),
                   score1 = c(90,78,92,69,86,73,82,85,91),
                   score2 = c(89,89,72,98,95,92,94,87,89),
                   score3 = c(91,88,93,89,90,78,87,98,89))

ID, year, score1, score2, score3
1, 1, 90, 89, 91
1, 2, 78, 89, 88
1, 3, 92, 72, 93
1, 4, 69, 98, 89
2, 1, 86, 95, 90
2, 2, 73, 92, 78
3, 1, 82, 94, 87
3, 2, 85, 87, 98
3, 3, 91, 89, 89
```

The data is unbalanced (different number of years for each `ID`). The `year` variable indicates the the n-th year that the specific `ID` was observed.

I want to create a linear effects model on `score1` as a function of `score2 + score3` and indexing by the variables `ID` and `year`.

This is how I approached the code using the package `lme4`:

```
lmer(score1 ~ (score2 + score3 | ID/year), data=data)
```

Is this possible to do in R?

Comment: Hi, can you, also, write which `package` that you are using, and `dput(head(data))` for you `data`, and then copy and paste it back to your post. It makes it easier for the community to help you out.

Comment: @Serkan thanks for the help, I made the edits there :)

Comment: In your full set, do both `score2` and `score3` vary (i.e. multiple values are recorded, at least in some groups) both within `ID` values and within years?  That will determine whether variation in the effect of a particular covariate (`score2` or `score3`) across particular grouping variables (`ID` or `year`) is identifiable or not ... you might also think about whether you want to consider trends in `score1` across years within units (in which case you would also add `year` as a numerical covariate/fixed effect)

Comment: No, `score2` and `score3` **do not** vary both within `ID` and `years` (i.e. for a certain `ID`, we cannot have 2 different values for `score2` in the same `year`, if this is what you meant?)

Comment: @BenBolker I believe that both `score2` and `score3` are *time variant* predictors. So, for each `ID`, there are several `year` rows (i.e. ID = 1 has 4 rows for each year). The values for `score2` & `score3` vary between these rows.

Answer (score 1):

Your current version won't work, but you have a few choices. I believe the *maximal model* is

```r
score1 ~ 1 + score2 + score3 + factor(year) + (1 + score2 + score3 + factor(year) | ID)
```

which evaluates

- the *population-level* effect of `score2`, `score3`, and the sampling sequence (`year`)
- the variation among individuals in the intercept (expected value of `score1` when `score2 == score3 == 0` in year 1); the effects of `score2` and `score3` on `score1`; and the effect of year of sampling.

This formulation is actually slightly overspecified  (and `lmer` will give a warning, which you would have to override using the `control` argument) because there is only one observation per ID/year combination, and we have specified a separate random effect for each one — so the `year|ID` effects and the residual variance are jointly unidentifiable.

A more typical model would be

```r
score1 ~ 1 + score2 + score3 + factor(year) + (1 + score2 + score3 | ID) + (1|ID:year)
```

This version assumes that the variation among years is *compound symmetric*, i.e. that the variability in each year is the same and that every pair of years within ID values has the same correlation.  However, it is still overspecified — for the same reasons described above (i.e. there is only a single observation per ID/year combination), the `(1|ID:year)` term is confounded with the residual variation.

Therefore, I would recommend

```r
score1 ~ 1 + score2 + score3 + factor(year) + (1 + score2 + score3 | ID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Just so you know, the dataset provided is an example I created of the real data. In reality, `ID` is a unique identifier for a list of sires (father horse), `score1` our response variable is the average rating of the dams (mother horse) that the sire visited that year, and `score2` is the average rating of the progeny that the sire produced that year. Does the fact that these variables are aggregated (average) change the analysis?

Comment: Not really.  I'm a little bit surprised that you're predicting dam ratings from progeny ratings and not vice versa, but whatever.  In principle you could (1) incorporate information on pedigrees (if you have them), (2) disaggregate information and  use *multi-membership models*, but both of these would be a bit challenging.